# Should I do 2 internships within one semester?

Tags: internship

I am currently pursuing an internship opportunity at a firm that requires approx 15-20 hours per week. I was also recently approached by another firm for an internship, which would be remote. I am a college student as well. Is it reasonable to do both internships at the same time? Will future employers question my stacked internships? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IMO this question is too opinion based to be answered here based on the site rules. It also is missing wayy too many details for anyone to give you good advice. Since you're in college, you likely have resources available that can help such as a career counselor. I would highly recommend pursuing those resources to help you decide rather than internet folk who don't know your class workload, time management capability, etc.

Comment: Honestly, it's better you do one internship well, than doing two internships in a half-fast way.

Comment: It sounds like you are a full time student with a part time internship. If you have two internships when are you going to sleep?

Comment: Does this mean that you plan to work 2 internships and NOT going to school (or NOT taking any class) this semester ?

Answer (score 3):

> Will future employers question my stacked internships?

There are people who work full time, and go to school part time.

If the two internships would be in that 15-20 hour level, that is what you would be doing.

Only you can decide what level of work and school you can handle.

The other issue is if the two companies knew about the other would they approve. If they are competitors they might not like you working for the other company.

Talk to somebody at your university or an advisor within your major. You could even talk to one of your professors.

If either internship is through the school, then your should talk to the school so you can understand your obligations. If you find yourself over worked, and have to quit  it might not look good for the university internship program.